# RavenDb-Get list from a list of ids

Tags: nosql, ravendb

I'm developing an events manager with RavenDb. The logged user can write a post in a place that follow and then see all posts in the user wall (home page). Every post can be mark as "Like" and "Favourite". A small structure like twitter or facebook.

Wich is the best way to get the posts by the places that I follow? I need to get the count of likes and favourites and if I already mark the post on viewmodel to send to the view and display the list. I'm trying like this, but throw the max requests exception.

```
            var myPlaces = this.SessionDb.Query<EventFollow>()
                .Where(ls => ls.UserId == User.Identity.Name)
                .Select(l => l.PlaceId);

            var listPosts = this.SessionDb
                .Advanced.LuceneQuery<Post>().WhereIn("PlaceId", myPlaces)
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(20)
                .ToList();


            List<PostViewModel> posts = new List<SpottedViewModel>();

            foreach (var p in listPosts)

            {
                PostViewModel vm = new PostViewModel();

                vm.Creator = p.UserCreatorId == User.Identity.Name;

                vm.Like =  this.SessionDb.Query<Lol>().Where(lol => lol.SpottedId == p.Id).Count();

                vm.Favourites = this.SessionDb.Query<Favourite>().Where(fa => fa.SpottedId == p.Id).Count();

                vm.Post= s;

                vm.IsLike = this.SessionDb.Query<Like>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.PostId == p.Id) != null;

                vm.IsFavourite = this.SessionDb.Query<Favourite>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.SpottedId == s.Id) != null;


                posts.Add(vm);
            }
```

I have these models:

```
public class Post
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UtenteCreatorId { get; set; }
    public string PlaceId { get; set; }
    public string Body{ get; set; }
}

public class Lol
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string PostId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string UserCreatorId { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Favourite
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string PostId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class EventFollow
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string PlaceId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you and sorry for my english! ;D

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here isn't really getting a list of documents from a list of IDs, you can do that by either using the IDocumentSession.Load method and sending in a list of document IDs, or by using WhereIn like you do. The problem is your model design.

It seems to me you have some serious re-design of your data models to do. It's strongly relational as it is now, it seems, and RavenDB isn't relational (or optimized towards relational models, anyway). It's hard for me to see exactly what your use cases are, but from what I can see I would probably save 'favourites' and 'likes' in the 'post' model, and put 'EventFollow' in the 'user' model.

Also, by RavenDB's ["safe by default"](http://ravendb.net/docs/intro/safe-by-default) principles, you're limited to 30 requests per session (per default, it's configurable). You have some [select N+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue) going on here so you'll most likely exceed those 30 requests, by far. That's why you get the exception.

Comment: yes, but in RavenDb Group (Google), an expert said to me that this data model is better than the precedent (like your) for eventually a lot of likes or favourites

Comment: That is surprising to me. Do you have a link to that discussion?